# Can I map SMS Storage to local folder?

Tags: c#, serial-port, gsm, at-command

Is there possibility that I can map my local folder to SMS storage?

I am using .NET (Serial port communication)

I know that I can specify storage of SMS using AT+CPMS= "MT" etc.

But I want all SMS to come directly to my system, not through a GSM modem.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

With my knowledge its a **NO**. For this purpose a better approach would be this-

1) Keep reading the port for any incoming messages using the `port.DataReceived event`.

2) You can use a *regular expression* to match the data present on the port with the message format. If there is a match, append this message to a file in the local drive.(*StreamWriter* can be useful for this).

3) To see that your modem or the SIM memory doesn't get filled up with the new messages, delete the read message as soon as you store it. This way you ill always have room for new incoming messages.

4) Once you set this functionality in your application you will endup with the messages being stored in file(local memory) and not being stored in the modem.